# How to create editable table in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel, data, datatable

I want to use Sharepoint to host a table that multiple people can edit (like an online spreadsheet, for example).  I have tried various things which have not worked:

I tried downloading a plugin for excel that has a "Share & Publish to Sharepoint" button, but when I use it I get a VB runtime error and a message saying could not connect to server.

I tried uploading a spreadsheet and creating a "data view" but once it is done, I get the message that "Standard view is being used because my browser doesn't support activeX".  I am using IE and have turned on all activeX permissions in Internet Options.

What is the easiest and best way to create an editable table in Sharepoint that anyone can edit, that can host drop-downs in the cells, and which is filterable?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you on SP2013? Why not use Office Web Apps?

Comment: Unfortunately the company I work for has banned the use of Office Web Apps, OneDrive, Google Docs and anything else that would work for this.

Comment: Datasheet view is suitable for your requirement. Also check activeX issue is coming to you only or others also.

Comment: I would like to use the datasheet view solution, but the Active X problem is frustrating.  I have tried 32 bit IE, Firefox and Chrome and none of them will work.  In IE, I went into the security settings and enabled all ActiveX, but still no love.

Comment: Check this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/59b06220-3016-4c3f-819c-adb0fa16f7f0/issues-with-the-custom-filter-in-datasheet-view

Comment: Can this datasheet be viewed by others (not editors, site admin). We have created a datasheet within a sharepoint extranet, and only the editors can see the datasheet/table. All other visitors can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a datasheet view. A datasheet view will allow anyone to edit, as long as you give them the correct permissions.

[image]

As long as you have a dropdown field on your list you can use it in this view.

[image]

You can also filter the list from the columns just like any other SP list:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the view settings you can enable "inline editing".

This enables a button which when clicked makes the row editable.

It even shows dropdowns when you have defined the column as multiple select.